# how to change text in Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I tried to do this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    t=new TextView(this); 

    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01); 
    t.setText("Step One: blast egg");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    t.setText("Step Two: fry egg");
```

but for some reason, only the second text shows up when I run it.  I think it might have something to do with the `Thread.sleep()` method blocking. So can someone show me how to implement a timer "asynchronously"?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason it only shows the second line is because `.setText()` replaces the entire "widget" with the text you tell it to set; INCLUDING text that you have already put there.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I just posted this answer in the android-discuss google group

If you are just trying to add text to the view so that it displays "Step One: blast egg Step Two: fry egg" Then consider using `t.appendText("Step Two: fry egg");`  instead of `t.setText("Step Two: fry egg");`

If you want to completely change what is in the `TextView` so that it says "Step One: blast egg" on startup and then it says "Step Two: fry egg" at a time later you can always use a

Runnable example sadboy gave

Good luck

Answer (score 145):

Your `onCreate()` method has several huge flaws:

1) `onCreate` **prepares** your Activity - so nothing that you do here will be made **visible** to the user until this method finishes! For example - you will never be able to alter a `TextView`'s text here more than **ONE** time as only the last change will be drawn and thus visible to the user!

2) Keep in mind that an Android program will - by default - run in **ONE** thread only! Thus: never use `Thread.sleep()` or `Thread.wait()` in your main thread which is responsible for your UI! (read ["Keep your App Responsive"](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) for further information!)

What your **initialization** of your Activity does is:

- for no reason you create a new `TextView` object `t`!
- you pick your layout's `TextView` in the variable `t` later.
- you set the text of `t` (but keep in mind: it will be displayed only **after** `onCreate()` finishes and the main event loop of your application runs!)
- you wait for **10 seconds** within your `onCreate` method - this **must never be done** as it stops all UI activity and will definitely force an ANR (Application Not Responding, see link above!)
- then you set another text - this one will be displayed as soon as your `onCreate()` method finishes and several other [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife) methods have been processed!

The solution:

1. Set text only once in `onCreate()` - this must be the first text that should be visible.
2. Create a `Runnable` and a `Handler`

   ```
   private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // do whatever you want to change here, like:
           t.setText("Second text to display!");
       }
   };
   private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   ```
3. install this runnable as a handler, possible in `onCreate()` (but read my advice below):

   ```
   // run the mUpdateUITimerTask's run() method in 10 seconds from now
   mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 10 * 1000);
   ```

Advice: be sure you know an `Activity`'s lifecycle! If you do stuff like that in `onCreate()`this will only happen when your `Activity` is created the **first** time! Android will possibly keep your `Activity` alive for a longer period of time, even if it's not visible!
When a user "starts" it again - and it is still existing - you will not see your first text anymore!

---

=> Always install handlers in `onResume()` and disable them in `onPause()`! Otherwise you will get "updates" when your `Activity` is not visible at all!
In your case, if you want to see your first text again when it is re-activated, you must set it in `onResume()`, not `onCreate()`!

Answer (score 15):

The first line of new text view is unnecessary

```
t=new TextView(this);
```

you can just do this

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
```

as far as a background thread that sleeps here is an example, but I think there is a timer that would be better for this. here is a link to a good example using a timer instead
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

```
    Thread thr = new Thread(mTask);
    thr.start();
}

Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // just sleep for 30 seconds.
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        runOnUiThread(done);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    };

    Runnable done = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                   // t.setText("done");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 6):

@user264892

I found that when using a String variable I needed to either prefix with an String of "" or explicitly cast to CharSequence.

So instead of:

```
String Status = "Asking Server...";
txtStatus.setText(Status);
```

try:

```
String Status = "Asking Server...";
txtStatus.setText((CharSequence) Status);
```

or:

```
String Status = "Asking Server...";    
txtStatus.setText("" + Status);
```

or, since your string is not dynamic, even better:

```
txtStatus.setText("AskingServer...");
```

Answer (score 3):

per your advice, i am using handle and runnables to switch/change the content of the TextView using a "timer". for some reason, when running, the app always skips the second step ("Step Two: fry egg"), and only show the last (third) step ("Step three: serve egg").

```
TextView t; 
private String sText;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mWaitRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        t.setText(sText);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mMonster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.monster1);

    t=new TextView(this); 
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01); 

    sText = "Step One: unpack egg";
    t.setText(sText);

    sText = "Step Two: fry egg";        
    mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 3000);

    sText = "Step three: serve egg";
    mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 4000);      
    ...
}
```

Comment: This cannot work! There is only ONE handler - how do you want your only existing mWaitRunnable runner to "know" that sText was once set to "Step Two" and then to "Step three"!!??
By the time it is called the first time (after 3 seconds) - the value of sText simply is "Step three"!

You should familiarize yourself with basic Java skills before trying Android programming! :-)

Comment: actually what i finally did was added a counter inside the runnable, if it's 1, the text will be this, if it's 2, the text will be this, etc.

Answer (score 0):

:) Your using the thread in a wrong way. 
Just do the following:

```
private void runthread()
{

splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized(this){

                        //wait 5 sec
                        wait(_splashTime);
                    }

                } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                finally {
                    //call the handler to set the text
                }
            }
        };

        splashTread.start(); 
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

setting the text to sam textview twice is overwritting the first written text.
So the second time when we use settext we just append the new string like

```
textview.append("Step Two: fry egg");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zordid @Iambda answer is great, but I found that if I put

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 10 * 1000);
```

in the run() method and

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 0);
```

in the onCreate method make the thing keep updating.