# How to print all key and values from HashMap in Android?

Tags: java, android, key, hashmap

I am trying to use HashMap in Android sample project. Now, am doing sample project for learn android. I just store keys and values in HashMap, i want to show the keys and their values in EditView. I followed below code in my sample project. But, first key and value only printing in EditView.

```
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
   map.put("iOS", "100");
   map.put("Android", "101");
   map.put("Java", "102");
   map.put(".Net", "103");
   
   Set keys = map.keySet();

   for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
       String key = (String) i.next();
       String value = (String) map.get(key);
       textview.setText(key + " = " + value);
   }
```

In EditView `iOS = 100` is only printing. I want to print all keys and their value in EditText. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this question and many others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Comment: hello Gopinath !! Your code to fetch and set the Hash map key value is correct but you are setting these value to only one textView .

Comment: Thanks to all. I got the answer. Once again i thank you all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, there are errors in your code, ie. you are missing a semicolon and a closing parenthesis in the for loop.

Then, if you are trying to append values to the view, you should use textview.appendText(), instead of .setText().

There's a similar question here: [how to change text in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview)

Comment: This is the best answer, but see also @Shadow for how to use Java 5 for and Map.Entry properly.

Answer (score 191):

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do it easier with Gson:

```
Log.i(TAG, "SomeText: " + new Gson().toJson(yourMap));
```

The result will look like:

```
I/YOURTAG: SomeText: {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Comment: Helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

It's because your TextView recieve new text on every iteration and previuos value thrown away. Concatenate strings by StringBuilder and set TextView value after loop.
Also you can use this type of loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    //to get key
    e.getKey();
    //and to get value
    e.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
HashMap <Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

Set<Integer> keys = hm.keySet();  //get all keys
for(Integer i: keys)
{
    System.out.println(hm.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't address the actual problem with the OP's code, which is almost identical.

Answer (score 5):

With Java 8:

```
map.keySet().forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + "->" + map.get(key)));
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: OP wants to print all keys and value pairs. I dont think any explanation is needed here. It is an very old thread, already answered, and also no brain thing. I have already written if someone is looking for a solution in Java8, he/she can do something like that.

Comment: mdev - There are many newbies here who would benefit from an explanation, even if it is obvious to an expert like you. 
If you would have provided an explanation, you might have discovered that your solution is incorrect; (teh "result" variable is unspecified). It should be:  

    map.keySet().forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + "->" + map.get(key)));

    Where the -> separates the parameters (left-side) from the implementation (right side). See https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/foreach-method-example/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Tihamer Thanks for pointing the typo. I have edited the answer.

Comment: The OP wants to *display* all the keys and values in a text field, and his only problem is in that part of it.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8

```
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    for (String entry : map.keySet()) {
      String value = map.get(entry);
      System.out.print(entry + "" + value + " ");
      // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String text="";

    for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext() 
       {
           String key = (String) i.next();
           String value = (String) map.get(key);
           text+=key + " = " + value;
       }

        textview.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested and working.

```
public void dumpMe(Map m) { dumpMe(m, ""); }
private void dumpMe(Map m, String padding) {
  Set s = m.keySet();
  java.util.Iterator ir = s.iterator();
  while (ir.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) ir.next();
    Object value = m.get(key);
    if (value == null) continue;
    if (value instanceof Map) {
      System.out.println (padding + key + " = {");
      dumpMe((Map)value, padding + "  ");
      System.out.println(padding + "}");          
    }
    else if (value instanceof String  ||
             value instanceof Integer ||
             value instanceof Double  ||
             value instanceof Float   ||
             value instanceof Long ) {

      System.out.println(padding + key + " = " + value.toString());
    }
    else { 
      System.out.println(padding + key + " = UNKNOWN OBJECT: " + value.toString());
      // You could also throw an exception here
    }      
  } // while

} // dumpme
```

Charles.

Answer (score 1):

To print all keys:

```
myMap.keys().toList().joinToString()
```

To print all entries:

```
myMap.map { "${it.key} :: ${it.value}" }.toList().joinToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
for (Object variableName: mapName.keySet()){
    variableKey += variableName + "\n";
    variableValue += mapName.get(variableName) + "\n";
}
System.out.println(variableKey + variableValue);
```

this code will make sure that all the keys are stored in a variable and then printed!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void dumpMe(Map m) { dumpMe(m, ""); }

private void dumpMe(Map m, String padding) 
{
    Set s = m.keySet();
    java.util.Iterator ir = s.iterator();
    while (ir.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key = (String) ir.next();
        AttributeValue value = (AttributeValue)m.get(key);
        if (value == null) 
            continue;
        if (value.getM() != null)
        {
            System.out.println (padding + key + " = {");
            dumpMe((Map)value, padding + "  ");
            System.out.println(padding + "}");          
        }
        else if (value.getS() != null  ||
                 value.getN() != null ) 
        {
            System.out.println(padding + key + " = " + value.toString());
        }
        else 
        { 
            System.out.println(padding + key + " = UNKNOWN OBJECT: " + value.toString());
            // You could also throw an exception here
        }      
    } // while
}

//This code worked for me.
```

Comment: Please look at [answer]

Answer (score -1):

For everyone who clicked on this to find out what the content of your HashMap is, the `toString` method ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString())) actually works with most objects. (note: a java array is not an object!)

So this woks perfectly fine for debugging purposes:

```
System.out.println(myMap.toString());

>>> {key1=value1, key2=value2}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin Answer

```
for ((key, value) in map.entries) {
    // do something with `key`
    // so something with `value`
}
```

You may find other solutions that include filterValues. Just keep in mind that retrieving a Key value using filterValues will include braces [].

```
val key = map.filterValues {it = position}.keys
```