# Java Android CountDownTimer malfunction

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I want my app to wait for a moment before changing the button text. I tried different things (wait(), Thread.sleep) but since I want the waiting time to be variable, I decided to make use of CountDownTimer. See the code below:

> ```
>   public void onClick(View buttonClicked) {
>     if (i == 0) {
>         button.setText("Wait");
>         waitingTime = (long) (Math.random() * 1000 + 10000);
>         new countdown(waitingTime, 1000);
>         time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
>         button.setText("Press");
>         i++;
> ```

For some reason this doesn´t work, and the program does not wait at all. Can anyone please help me? I did not fill the CountDownTimer with anything since I figured that it should only wait for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is also variable:

```
try {
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if(i==0) {
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {



@Override               

public void run() {
txtView.setText("please wait...");
}
});

while(counter < 1000) {
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
counter +=100;
}

txtView.setText("press");


i++;


}

}
```

Increase the thread timing according to ur needs. And if needed write this code in the function where you are passing the sleep value

EDIT

mHandler = new Handler();
         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btn.setText("wait");
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn.setText("press");
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the Thread.sleep and it does wait but not the text on the button isn´t changed... How can I show my code correctly?

>     public void onClick(View buttonClicked) {
  button.setText("Wait");
  if (i == 0) {
   waitingTime = (long) (Math.random() * 1000 + 3000);
   try {
     Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
   time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   button.setText("Press");
   i++;

Comment: YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     
     @Override
     public void run() {
      button.setText("Wait");
     }
    }); try this instead of just button.setText("Wait");

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview?answertab=votes#tab-top)