# Android - passing text with intent

Tags: android-intent

this is my first time making a question here i hope i'm doing it right, my question is if there's a way to pass a text to a XML element in android without having to do it through the setContentView() so i can pass the text to a specific element and not have it as the whole content in the activity. thanks in advance.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
tv.setText("whatever you want");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the TextView be a part of the layout, and then use [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) to obtain a pointer to the TextView (without having the TextView take up the entire content of the layout).

Comment: this is the code i have but it crash every time i press the button that take me to the activity with this code.

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textview.setTextSize(40);
textview.setText(message);