# Android beginner needs some knowledge

Tags: android, textview

Noob `Android` developer here looking for clarification about this:

To show the message on the screen, create a `TextView` widget and set the text using **setText()**. Then add the `TextView` as the root view of the `Activity`’s layout by passing it to `setContentView()`.

Specifically what does it mean to `set the text` and `root view` mean? Thanks.

Comment: From here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=cn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you a complete newby, then probably "adding the TextView as the root view of the activity’s layout" (whatever it means) is not the right place to start. Try to understand the very basics by learning your first project structure. Assuming that you work in Eclipse and haven't changed the default activity (MainActivity.java) and layout file (activity_main.xml) names when creating the project, do as follows:

- Go to res/layout/activity_main.xml and add the following line to the TextView definition:

  android:id="@+id/tv"

So, your activity_main.xml should look like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Go to src/your.package.name.MainActivity.java and add the lines:

  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

  tv.setText("Your text");

If TextView is highlighted with red, press Ctrl+Shift+O (Windows) to import the needed classes. You should see:

```
package your.package.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Your text");
}

}
```

- Run your app.

Answer (score 1):

> set the text

means set the text that displays on the `TextView`

> root view

means the very base `View` of the `Activity`'s layout, the `Activity` is build by `View`s, so that the `Activity` is visiable, the root means the first tag in the layout xml file.

Comment: ...import android.widget.TextView;...                                                                                  TextView setText = new TextView(this);
     setText.setTextSize(40);
     setText.setText(message);      like this?

Comment: The static text and textsize usually are set in the layout xml file, but you can also set them dynamically in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
setText("Your Text")
```

This function sets the text which is given as arguement to the TextView widget (child).Its is almost like `System.out.println(" ")` or `System.out.print(" ") which displays the string to screen.But here setText(" ") displays to mobile screen.Actually the child(`TextView`) needs parent(Layout).So`addView()` must be used to add this child to the parent.

```
setContentView()
```

Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.To know more about this click this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)..

Comment: ok so I have my Textview widget imported. is this line ---> TextView textView = new TextView(this); where i need to pass in setText?

Comment: TextView textView = new TextView(this);
//set text now
textView.setText("YourText");
//and add this to your layout.
yourLayout.addView(textView);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview

http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-1-3-how-to-modify-textview-in-java-code-findviewbyid-settext-and-gettext-methods/

See these links to know more...Just google anything before you post here...